# SEND EMAIL BASED ON CONDITIONS (SAS)

Tags: email, if-statement, sas, conditional-statements

I found the below code (untouched) in this forum which is very close to what i was looking for however am having some issues when tweaking;

```
data Millenium_Falcon;
han='1';
luke='0';
darth='0';
run;

filename myemail EMAIL
to="me@lando.com"
cc="me@lando.com"
from="me@lando.com"
subject="Millenium Falcon"
importance="HIGH"
;

data _null_;
set Millenium_Falcon ;
file myemail;
IF (Luke = '1' and Darth = '0') then do;
    put "Han,";
    put " ";
    put "Look out for the asteroids.";
    put " ";
    put "Thank you.";
    put " ";
    put "Obi";
end;
else do;
    put '!EM_ABORT!';
end;
stop;
run;
```

Before tweaking, this code works fine however when i try to point to my data set (removing Millennium_Falcon step above) which just contains meta data from dictionary.tables (libname,memname,modate) and change the if statement to

```
IF (memname = 'TEST' and datepart(modate) = date()) then do;
```

the email does not send. It is almost like the data step (below) must be present (acting like datalines) for this to work.

```
data Millenium_Falcon;
han='1';
luke='0';
darth='0';
run;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Aaron

Comment: What happens if you run the final data step with the FILE statement commented out? Does it PUT '!EM_ABORT!' to the SAS log?

Comment: Yes, it does show in the log.

Comment: So that is why no EMAIL was sent. If that is not what you expected given your data then debug your logic to get the results you want. For example  are you sure that there are any tables with MODATE value of today's date?

Comment: Yes, there is 1 of 3 tables with MODATE value of today's date so I am expecting 1 email to be sent notifying me that it has been modified today.

Comment: Do you want to send one or two emails if there are two records that match your criteria?

Comment: 2 emails. so if 2 tables have modate value of today's date then 2 emails will be sent, however that is a few steps ahead as i am just trying to get it to send just 1 email at first to get a working example, i can later adapt it for multiple emails to be sent.

Comment: Read the manual on using email directives. You can use directives to do thinks like send the email, change the target email address, reset, etc in addition to just aborting.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific manual??? As i have already scowered the net and read many documents on this and am still struggling.

Comment: Also should have mentioned i am very new to SAS. Could you comment your lines of code please?

Comment: Use a google search like this should help.  http://www.google.com/search?q=%40sas.com+email+directives+9.4 should find manuals or like this to find papers by users. https://www.google.com/search?q=lex+jansen+email+directives

Comment: Many thanks for your help. that seems to work. Now all i have to do is figure out how not to send an email again once already sent??? any ideas??? Thanks.

Comment: If you can't get email directives to send multiple emails then you could always wrap the code you have for sending one into a macro and call it multiple times.

Comment: I have used your below code 3 times in order to send 3 different emails which works fine, however once a condition is met and an email is sent i don't want to keep sending out the same email as this will clutter up peoples inbox's. (this job is being scheduled via windows scheduler)

Comment: You need to record what email you sent somewhere. Could be as simple as boolean or date_email_sent field in your dataset(s). You should probably start a new thread for that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something more like this that will abort when no records meet the criteria and otherwise generate a list of the values that do.

```
data _null_;
  file myemail;
  if _n_=1 and eof then put '!EM_ABORT!';
  set have end=eof ;
  where (memname = 'TEST' and datepart(modate) = date()) ;
  put memname= modate= ;
run;
```